# checkselfpermission throw a Null Exception in fragment - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions, android-context

I have a question and I want to hear an answer for this cause I really search it for a long time and it really doesn't matter what I'm doing I still get the error. Here is the code that I wrote :

```
if (getContext() != null) {
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {}
```

Before I try to load the Map I'm checking the permission for he Locations so inside onMapLoaded I'm checking like above.

Is there any tricks or is this a bug in ContextCompat ?

Error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)'
>   on a null object reference

Comment: post the whole stacktrace and more code

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 100);
}
```